# Replace constant with expression

Tags: replacement

How can I replace a constant `a` in a certain expression with a function `f[z_]:=1+z`?

I tried the following:

```
expr = a/c
(*a/c*)
expr = Replace[expr, a -> f[z]]
(*a/c*)
```

The desired result would be `expr=(1 + z)/c`

Comment: If really want to update `expr`, try `expr = expr /. a -> f[z]`

Comment: Or use the correct function name, which is ReplaceAll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third argument of `Replace` to specify the level as 1:

```
f[x_] := 1 + x;
expr = a/c;
expr = Replace[expr, a -> f[z], 1]
```

> (1 + z)/c